# Vote to reopen my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [Physical transformation associated with a Pseudo-Orthogonal matrix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/427801/)

I was closed because of a unclear ques. Now I have reworded it, it is more clear, still, No one opened it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was not closed for being unclear – indeed, it has always been pretty clear what you are asking, even before the recent edit.

The problem is that it does not show any research effort. If you google "pseudo-orthogonal group", the very first result is the Wikipedia entry [Indefinite orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group) where you can read that

> In physics, the [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) O(1, 3) is of central importance, being the setting for electromagnetism and special relativity.

Clicking on "Lorentz group" takes you to the corresponding entry, which has a rather detailed discussion of the group, and plenty of examples.

Thus, it would have taken you less than a minute to answer your own question by just typing it into google. Such questions are considered off-topic here, because we expect users to try and find the answer themselves before posting the question here: if you are not willing to spend some of your own time in trying to find the answer, we will not waste ours in providing the solution for you. These are the rules of the game.

Comment: It is not that I didn't put efforts to find the answer. I searched a lot before posting.,  But I was unable to find the required matrix.  Anyway thank you for clearing the confusion regarding the closing my Ques.

Comment: @SachinKumar Ah, I'm sure you put effort. The problem is that the question itself did not *show* it. Note that I always talked about *showing* effort (both here and when voting to close the OP). We cannot try and guess whether people made an effort before posting; we can only judge what's written in the post itself.

Comment: Yes, I understand, Thank you :)